# Event not added to calendar in ios 5

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm providing a button for users to add a all day event to their calendar with two alarms as follows:

```
myEvent.title     = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The Event"];
myEvent.startDate = theeventdate;
myEvent.endDate   = theeventdate;
myEvent.allDay = YES;
NSMutableArray *myAlarmsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                 [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset: -86400],
                                 [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset: -172800],nil];
myEvent.alarms = myAlarmsArray;
[myEvent setCalendar:[eventEntry defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
[myAlarmsArray release];
NSError *err;

[eventEntry saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

This worked fine in iOS 4.x and for *me* in iOS 5 on iPad. However I'm getting reports that nothing is added to the users calendar under iOS 5. I observed this problem today on a 4S with basic default calendar: no crash, no hang, just no event added to the calendar. Unfortunately I deployed the app without logging any potential error returned by saveEvent. Am I doing something wrong here or has any one else seen this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Best I can tell the following update to the eventEntry saveEvent fixes the problem:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0")) {
    [eventEntry saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];
} else {
    [eventEntry saveEvent:myEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Note the explicit commit:YES.

Comment: Another way to check is the checking `[eventEntry respondsToSelector:@selector(saveEvent:span:commit:error:)`, but the effect is the same.